# Should I move on return when variables are not local

Tags: c++, c++11, move

A have a few questions regarding copy elision and move.
Let's assume I have the following code:

```
class A {};

class B {
public:
    A get1() const {
        A local_var;
        return local_var;
    }
    A get1bad() const {
        A local_var;
        return std::move(local_var);
    }
    A get2() const {
        return member_var;
    }
    A get3() const {
        return std::move(member_var);
    }
private:
    A member_var;
};
```

I read a lot of people saying to not do move on return.
From what I gather it's because with copy elision, on case get1, the compiler will not call constructor + move constructor but rather just one call to the default constructor, while case get1bad forces the compiler to call constructor + move.

My question is regarding cases where the variable is not local (get2 vs get3).
In that case, the variable is constructed anyway in the class. In get2 there's not really any optimization that I can see being possible. In this case, if I don't really care about ensuring class B has a valid A object, wouldn't it be better to actually move? Wouldn't it just call the move constructor which is generally cheaper than the copy constructor?

Comment: Yes, for non-local objects it will be better to return by moving but in your case, the member function `get3` is `const` so the data member `member_var` will be copied here aswell. Tools like clang-tidy will let you know when you're making such mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read a lot of people saying to not do move on return. From what I gather it's because with copy elision, on case get1, the compiler will not call constructor + move constructor but rather just one call to the default constructor, while case get1bad forces the compiler to call constructor + move.

If the operand to a `return` statement is just the name of a local variable, then `std::move` is basically implicitly applied. So at best `return std::move(local_var);` is redundant. This is a special rule for `return`. It doesn't apply elsewhere.

However, using `return std::move(local_var);` makes it so that the mandatory copy elision rules do not apply anymore, which is why it is not only redundant, but even worse than just `return local_var;`.

---

> My question is regarding cases where the variable is not local (get2 vs get3). In that case, the variable is constructed anyway in the class. In get2 there's not really any optimization that I can see being possible. In this case, if I don't really care about ensuring class B has a valid A object, wouldn't it be better to actually move? Wouldn't it just call the move constructor which is generally cheaper than the copy constructor?

In your examples all member functions are `const` qualified. Therefore the type of `std::move(member_var)` will be `const A&&`. The move constructor takes a `A&&`, not `const A&&`. Therefore no move will happen and the copy constructor will be used for both `get2` and `get3`'s return values.

If you remove the `const` qualifiers, then yes `return std::move(member_var);` makes sense in that case and allows a move construction rather than copy construction. Copy/move elision is not possible in either case, since variable is not local to the function.

---

It is unlikely that you wouldn't care about the state of `member_var` after calling a member function, so it is unlikely that this will make sense in practice. If at all I would qualify the member function with `&&`, so that it is only used if the class instance is an rvalue, which is the only case I can think of where one doesn't care about the object state after the call to the member function.

Comment: Hi, thanks, alright that's exactly what I wanted to know, was trying to implement a class like std::future, that's cool, it does clarify my question.

Answer (score 4):

```
A get3() const {
    return std::move(member_var);
}
```

You have a const function, so the member is also considered const and will not move anyway.

You could consider `A get3() &&` to move the member when you have a temporary `B`. Maybe, if that happens often.

Having a getter that *always* destroys the class' value, even when it is an lvalue, seems like a rare use case.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know, was trying to do a std::future-like class (roll my own implementation just for shits and giggles, definitely not something I'd normally do, just to learn)